# What is the best way to handle errors for promises?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I have a config load function that loads some data from a json file and resolves a promise with it.

When I call the load function I'm wondering what the better way is to handle errors. From what I understand and can there are two options.

```
public config: any = this.configProvider.load()
    .then(data => this)
    .then(error => console.error(error));
```

versus

```
public config: any = this.configProvider.load()
    .then(data => this)
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
```

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278280/promise-then-vs-then-catch

Comment: use catch at the end of promise chain.

Comment: did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45219120/2545680) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not correct:

```
public config: any = this.configProvider.load()
    .then(data => this)
    .then(error => console.error(error));
```

It will not catch any errors. Errors are promises that are rejected. What you need is this:

```
public config: any = this.configProvider.load()
    .then(data => this, error => console.error(error))
```

Pass the function that catches rejected promises as a second parameter.

But the approach with `catch` is more readable and intuitive to me:

```
public config: any = this.configProvider.load()
    .then(...)
    .then(...)
    .then(...)
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
```

But you can achieve the same with the following:

```
public config: any = this.configProvider.load()
    .then(...)
    .then(...)
    .then(..., function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with your first example!

Comment: @AugieLuebbers, you're welcome, thanks for accepting the answer, good luck

Answer (score 1):

`.catch` is the good option here.

`.catch` catches errors from the process of loading up the json / invalid json, double `.then` execute regardless if error occurs. so if you get no errors, the second `.then` will still execute

Answer (score 0):

They both achieve the same goal of logging your error. However, the context does not change when you step inside of an arrow function. The value of `this` will change inside a `function` block. For example, if you need to use keys associated with the object enclosing your function, you may be better off using a `function` block, since, then you can refer to the enclosing object by using the `this` keyword. 
Additionally, as far as I know, using the `.catch` at the end of your chain will catch any errors encountered in the promise chain up until that point. However using `.then` will catch an error of the immediately preceding `.then` block and not any from before.